# Not Found Error when trying to run node index.js

Tags: node.js

I have installed Node.js and now I want to run some mock API.

*index.js*:

```
const app = require('koa')()
const cors = require('koa-cors')
const logger = require('koa-logger')
const router = require('koa-router')()

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function getRandomDeliveryLocation() {
    let locs = [
        { lat: 22.319181, lng: 114.170008, address: 'Mong Kok' },
        { lat: 22.336093, lng: 114.155288, address: 'Cheung Sha Wan' },
        { lat: 22.335538, lng: 114.176169, address: 'Kowloon Tong' }
    ]

    return locs[ getRandomInt( 0, locs.length ) ]
}

function getRandomDeliveryDescription( index ) {
    if ( index % 3 === 0 ) {
        return 'Deliver documents to Andrio'
    }

    let desp = [
        'Deliver documents to Andrio',
        'Gift pets to Leviero',
        'Gift pets to Alan'
    ]
    return desp[ getRandomInt( 0, desp.length ) ]
}

function getRandomDeliveryItem( index ) {
    return {
            id: index,
            description: getRandomDeliveryDescription( index ),
            imageUrl: 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/lalamove-mock-api/images/pet-'
+ getRandomInt( 0, 9 ) + '.jpeg',
            location: getRandomDeliveryLocation()
    }
}

function delay(sec) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, sec * 1000))
}

router.get('/pets', function* () {

    let cap = 70
    let offset = parseInt( this.query.offset, 10 )
    let limit = parseInt( this.query.limit, 10 )
    if ( isNaN( offset ) || isNaN( limit ) || offset < 0 || limit < 0 ) {
        this.status = 400
        return
    }

    yield delay(getRandomInt(0, 5))
    if (!getRandomInt(0, 9)) {
        this.status = 500
        return
    }

    this.body = []
    for ( let i = offset; i < offset + limit && i < cap; i++ ) {
        this.body.push( getRandomDeliveryItem( i ) )
    }

})

app
    .use(logger())
    .use(cors())
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods())

app.listen(8080)
console.log('Mock server started at port 8080')
```

It gives me:

> Not Found Error when opening the localhost:8080/pets.

Am I missing something and how to fix it?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you intentionally using the `generator function` in router definition?

Comment: @planet_hunter yes to get random items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async`/`await` instead of a generator function, which works with the code you've posted. Here's what that looks like (I've made additional changes to fix additional problems):

```
router.get('/pets', async function (ctx) {
    let cap = 70
    let offset = parseInt( ctx.request.query.offset, 10 )
    let limit = parseInt( ctx.request.query.limit, 10 )
    if ( isNaN( offset ) || isNaN( limit ) || offset < 0 || limit < 0 ) {
        ctx.response.status = 400
        return
    }

    await delay(getRandomInt(0, 5))
    if (!getRandomInt(0, 9)) {
        ctx.response.status = 500
        return
    }

    ctx.response.body = []
    for ( let i = offset; i < offset + limit && i < cap; i++ ) {
        ctx.response.body.push( getRandomDeliveryItem( i ) )
    }
})
```

The changes here are:

1. Removed the `*` from `function *` to stop it from being a generator function.
2. Changed to `async function` so that `await` can be used.
3. Use `await` instead of `yield` to wait for your `delay` promise to resolve.
4. Switch from `this.query` to `ctx.request.query`.
5. Switch from `this.status` and `this.body` to `ctx.response.status` and `ctx.response.body`.

Comment: Done you are  Pro in node.js. Can you please explain me what had gone wrong?

Comment: Sorry that took so long, I made a few edits over time as I made a few typos and it was hard for you to keep up. The main problem was that you were using a generator function instead of either a promise-returning function or an `async`/`await` function. After that, you were using `this` which doesn't refer to anything inside that function. This is why we had to use `ctx` which has both the `request` and the `response` properties.

Comment: Guys checkout this repo, I just copied this asnwer and made work there. Hope it will help. https://repl.it/@ManojChalode/IndelibleFrayedBsddaemon working url - https://indeliblefrayedbsddaemon--manojchalode.repl.co/pets?limit=10&offset=0